# range restriction to attributes, DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I'm trying to make restriction based on a range of value given to a date value, using this :

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1971", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString())]
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

But, I got an error saying that I cannot use variables into that restriction. How can I achieve that, please ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Since the Attributes expect constant values, you would have to implement your custom metadata provider. You would then inject the end value of your range dynamically.

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
     protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
     {
          base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

          foreach (var attribute in attributes.OfType<RangeAttribute>())
          {
               if (attribute.OperandType == typeof(DateTime)
               {
                    attribute.Maximum = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString();
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Another option, as suggested in Abbas' answer is to create a custom validation attribute. Something along these lines:

```
public class CustomDateRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
     public CustomDateRangeAttribute()
     {
          base();
          base.Maximum = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not specified in the [**RangeAttribute Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [**RangeAttribute Constructor (Type, String, String)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679255%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation, the constructor expects constant values.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response, but, how to fix that in my case ?

Comment: I think your only option is writing a custom range validator that does the DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)-part during validation.

Comment: When you apply an attribute with the `[Attr(a, b, c)]` syntax, the arguments `a`, `b` and `c` must always be compile-time constants. That is a limitation of C# and the way attributes are "burned" into the output file at compile-time. So that does not need to be in the spec for `RangeAttribute` class. In other situations you can use non-consts, for example `var myTest = new RangeAttribute(notConst.GetType(), CalculateSomeString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString());` but this won't help the asker with his problem, of course.